# Run code block in functions.php ONLY when theme is activated. Use register_activation_hook?

Tags: wordpress, themes

I have a specific bit of setup code for my theme that I only want to process when the theme is first activated. I was under the impression that I could use register_activation_hook for this, but it does not appear to be working.

Example...

In my functions.php file, I want the doThemeSetup() function to run only upon theme activation and no other time...

```
function doThemeSetup(){
  //stuff here only runs once, when theme is activated
}

register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'doThemeSetup');
```

UPDATE: Since posting this question, I have found that register_activation_hook is only available to plugins and not themes.

I have found a means to do similar action in themes but I'm getting inconsistent results:

```
if ( is_admin() && isset($_GET['activated'] ) && $pagenow == 'themes.php' ) 
{
  //do something
}
```

The code above does not seem to run when the theme is first activated, but rather when the theme is switched to from another theme.

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a workaround than solution, but if everything other fails you can try it:

```
<?php
if (get_option('themename_installed') != 'true'){
    if (doThemeSetup()){
        add_option('themename_installed','true');
    }

}
?>
```

This way the doThemeSetup is ran only once.

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * Install script to create databasetables and then insert default data.
 * And inserting defautl theame settings.
 * Only run if theme is being activated for the first time.
 */

$flag = get_option('first_time_theme_activation_check');

if ( $flag == false && is_admin()) 
{

  // put your code to run when theme is activated at first time by admin



  // update option at last
     update_option('first_time_theme_activation_check', 'true');
}
```